# How to build image with ultrasound sensors HC-SR04

Tags: sensors, sound

There is a simple algorithm on Wikipedia: [how to build ultrasound image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_ultrasound#From_sound_to_image). And I want to build one. Resolution and presision are of no importance, I just want to do this for the case of study - I want to make such an "image 1D+depth slice" of a 20m^2 room. So I may just use these low frequency sensors - 1cm is enough.

So, as stated in the article, I need a phased array (to direct wave). And accidentally I have a couple of Arduino sensors HC-SR04:

[image]

Everyone uses them, but I stumbled how to use them. Interface seems to be totally weird, insuffient and unusable. Despite there are (visually) so many logic ICs soldered on the back.. So why is it designed so poorly and how to fix that?

Could you help me - where and what would you solder/desolder to use it for ultrasound imaging? I think that sensors itself could suit for this task.

PS. Basically I need to measure echoes delay (for depth) and echoes streight (for pixel brightness)

It should work on the [phased array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array) principles, without rotating, moving, without using any motors. Desired radiation pattern is illustrated by following animations:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it even possible to draw a 2D image with this sensor? There is just one receiver so the triangulation of the source of the echo is impossible. The algorithm description in Wikipedia looks more like "How to draw an owl" meme. https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/572078-how-to-draw-an-owl In reality this task is very complicated. Technically You can use this sensor with 2 steppers to draw image pixel-by-pixel but it will take minutes.

Comment: @FilipFranik As it was stated: "And accidentally I have a couple of Arduino sensors HC-SR04".. So its possible. Also, sorry, I dont learn memes (head space is way limited to trash it with remembering useless memes).

Comment: What I meant was "the description of algorithm in Wikipedia is misleadingly simple, whereas in reality the task is not". Having couple of those sensors helps, but you will need a device that sends only a single pulse of sound and then several microphones listen to the result (those sensors can't do that), then the tricky part comes, you need to look for local minimums and maximums in the result trying to match them between sensors. This way you can triangulate (in 3D) what pixels should be brighter. This is a very interesting (and difficult) project, and I will think more about it.

Comment: @FilipFranik My PC sound card (EMU1212) has 2 Output and 2 Input channels; It can easily sample at 192khz, meaning that generating/recording square wave at 48khz frequency is a simple task, as well as aligning/analysing phase (in software) - just shift signal start in left or right channel.. And 2 SR sensors has exactly 2 transmitters and 2 recievers (to be desoldered from such a poorly designed sensors). But also they have some logic, I wondered can I reuse a part of it?

Comment: The datasheet for the sensor doesn't say what chips are located on it. Could you please write the numbers you see on them in the question?. According to here http://osoyoo.com/2018/08/arduino-lesson-ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04-module/ they are two LM324 (quad op-amps) and MAX3232 (RS323 transceiver) This would explain the strange interface since this looks like a clever hack to lower cost of the sensor.

Comment: This might interrest you http://uglyduck.vajn.icu/ep/archive/2014/01/Making_a_better_HC_SR04_Echo_Locator.html and this http://www.pcserviceselectronics.co.uk/arduino/Ultrasonic/electronics.php There is open-hardware upgraded HC-SR04 board that replaces custom Chinese microcontroller with ATtiny24. Technically you can then upload any program you want on it.

Comment: @FilipFranik One amp is really the 324, second is unnamed, no markings on it. And a "max202 cse+1409" IC. Sensors are visually the same, but are non-measurable with standart multimeter. It gives infinite resistance even at 2MOhm. And zero voltage even at 200mV scale when loud sound pushed into it. So they are neither inductors, nor capacitors (upd: I think they're capacitors operated at microvolts scale). And it all is kind of "totally chineese magical stuff".. Thanks, I will read the info :)

Comment: This would be a fair first attempt. It may not fit your end-goal, but it's a good intermediary step: https://youtu.be/PlB3c2WaaBg

Comment: @Paul This could not help me, because it utilizes motor, but not phased array manipulation, to direct sound.

Comment: @jsotola It means that you have 2 sensors. By sensor I assume a transmitter and a reciever in one device. So you have 2 transmitters that could allow you to direct wave without rotating or moving your head to which it is attached. But by playing with wave phase so they cancel out. Having 2 recievers would allow to guess direction of a sound, as you ears do. That would give you one dimension: 1D. Another trick is that you could recieve more than 1 echo, that would give you depth, or second dimension. You havent even bothered reading wiki article in my question! It is described there very well!

Comment: @jsotola I want to build a 2D plane, where one dimension is horisontal and lies in the line, connecting human eyes, or ears. And second dimension is a depth. That gives a plane. It could be a fan-shaped image (like medical), showing rough approximation of room (and obstacles the plane crossects). I want to achieve it without rotating actual sensor (not using any kind of motor), that's primary goal. I think that more clever echoes processing could be required, than just "measuring time". For instance, I could need to process arrival phases. And also I'd like to measure echo strenght as well.

Comment: @jsotola I think 2 tranmitto-recievers (sensors) could build a fan-shaped figure in a plane, and 3 sensors could build a 3D space figure, limited by some cone, or even tetrahedra.. but all this "is not exact" - I've just started studying this field :)

Comment: @jsotola I've added animation to original question to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Comment: @xakepp35 i have heard of using a microphone array to record, at a distance, the voice of one person in a crowded room ...... your project is very similar ..... there may be detailed information on the web

Comment: @jsotola May. A link could be much useful than a mere rumors..   ;-)

Comment: This certainly cannot be done with these modules. But you should be able to reuse the ultrasonic piezo elements. If you really want to be a cheapskate you might be able to also reuse the op amps. Tomorrow I will try to write a somewhat answer, but you won't get a ready to use solution here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgz7Cx-qSFw